# Setting up the line spaces in references (Latex/BibTex Overleaf)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran

I am using overleaf to format a paper with IEEEtran document class with BibTex. However, I want to reduce line-spacing between lines within reference entries (not between the entries themselves).

I have seen over internet, that we can use setspace package and set up space where we use the "\printbibliography" command to reduce spacing. However, as soon as I include setspace package on top of the page, I see spacing changes in tables in my paper in particular.

Suggest me something to tackle this issue.

Tx.

CODE:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{reference}

\begin{document}
jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{who2020,mirtchouk2017recognizing} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses
\begin{table}[!htp]
          \vspace{-4mm}
\caption{SBL - Model Summaries}
\label{tab:popular_sparse_bayesian_models}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{2.5cm}}
\hline\hline
& & &  \\
\hline  
\textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Method}  & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Priors}  \\ [1.0ex] 
\hline
RVMs\\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{8pt}\cite{mirtchouk2017recognizing} & RVM  & Sigmoid & Zero-mean Gaussian \\
\rule{0pt}{8pt}\cite{mirtchouk2017recognizing} & Fast RVM & Sigmoid & Zero-mean Gaussian  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{who2020,mirtchouk2017recognizing} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses

jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{who2020,mirtchouk2017recognizing} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses


\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
  \newpage
\fi
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As always on this site, you are much more likely to get any help if you provide a minimal self contained example that others can copy and test for them self. If you use non-standard classes please also provide a link to where these classes can be downloaded from.

Comment: I am using \usepackage{setspace}

Comment: As soon as I put this line on top of the document, it stretches the spacing within tables. I dont understand, why it happens. Is it by default? If so - how can we overwrite it?

Comment: How should we know when we don't know what you are doing in your document. Sorry, if you are unable to provide code to be tested by others, then we cannot help.

Comment: @daleif `IEEEtran` is actually quite a common class available on CTAN. So in this particular case there doesn't really seem to be a need to provide a link to it, don't you think? (I do agree with you in terms of the missing MWE though)

Comment: @MarkusG. link generally refers to classes not available from CTAN. For example the Springer classes tends to never be on CTAN

Comment: Then we agree. The OP explicitly mentioned `IEEEtran`, so I was confused about your comment.

Comment: My question can be rewritten, or re-asked as ---- does setspace package override the line-spacing, even if you don't call  "\setstretch" etc ? It seems, it does. So how should I control it. I am using IEEEtran. I can share code, all of it. But its like 1000 lines, with dozens of paragraphs..

Comment: @rockstone435 - Please consider creating a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), with emphasis on *minimal*, that replicates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: Please see the original post. I have edited it and included the code that shows the problem If you simply copy this thing, and put it in latex, remove "setspace" (line 3), you will see that the table gets formatted with different spacing. Now, put it again, and you will see the difference. Additionally, the actual problem is to adjust line spacing within the references items (not with him items, but within references themselves). @all

Comment: Probably not directly related to the issue, but definitely relevant: The code as shown uses code for referencing with BibTeX and for `biblatex`. The two methods are incompatible and you will get errors. `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` is a BibTeX-based command, but `\usepackage{biblatex}` and `\printbibliography` are for `biblatex`. (Furthermore, `\bibliography` must be used in the preamble with `biblatex` and in the document body with BIbTeX.) You can only choose one of the two and the code as shown produces several errors related to the bibliography. ...

Comment: ... Overleaf does not show errors as prominently as it should (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864), but the code definitely errors. I'm assuming your are using `IEEEtran` because you want to submit to an IEEE publication. In that case I strongly suggest you do not use `biblatex` and instead follow the documentation of your publication venue and the `IEEEtran` class.

Comment: Yes - it doesnt prompt, and lets you run it, to get the PDF at-least. I will remove those lines and see if there is a difference.

Comment: The thing is you cannot rely on the PDF to make sense after an error. I think it is a bit dishonest of Overleaf to even show the PDF after an error, because it gives the wrong impression that things are fine. Anyway, fixing your bibliography setup is important, but will probably have no bearing on the actual problem you are asking about.

Comment: The problem, I stated, is with setspace, as soon as you put that line, the table spacing behaves differently, whereas no changes are done to it directly. So it appears, as if this statement has some default impact.. I want to retain the original spacing, and use this package to adjust line spacing within references. I hope I have made my point clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `IEEEtran` class then that is presumably for publication with the IEEE. In that case I don't think it is a good idea to try and mess with the spacing in your document: The settings in the class are what they are for a reason and depending on the publishing workflow your changes might not even make it to the published paper.

Anyway, the issue is caused by an "incompatibility" between `setspace` and `IEEEtran`. `IEEEtran` switches tables to a smaller font with

```
\def\table{\def\@floatboxreset{\reset@font\footnotesize\@setminipage}\@float{table}}
```

and `setspace` resets the line spacing in all floats with

```
\let\latex@xfloat=\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat #1[#2]{%
  \latex@xfloat #1[#2]%
  \def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
  \normalsize
}
```

But `setspace`'s definition explicitly sets `\normalsize` overriding `IEEEtran`'s `\footnotesize`.

Here is a way to work around that

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat\latex@xfloat
\def\table{%
  \def\@floatboxreset{%
    \reset@font\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\footnotesize\@setminipage}%
  \@float{table}}
\@namedef{table*}{%
  \def\@floatboxreset{%
    \reset@font\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\footnotesize\@setminipage}%
  \@dblfloat{table}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{article-full,incollection-full} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses
\begin{table}[!htp]
          \vspace{-4mm}
\caption{SBL - Model Summaries}
\label{tab:popular_sparse_bayesian_models}
%\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{2.5cm}}
\hline\hline
& & &  \\
\hline  
\textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Method}  & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Priors}  \\ [1.0ex] 
\hline
RVMs\\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{8pt}\cite{article-full} & RVM  & Sigmoid & Zero-mean Gaussian \\
\rule{0pt}{8pt}\cite{article-full} & Fast RVM & Sigmoid & Zero-mean Gaussian  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{article-full,incollection-full} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses

jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{article-full,incollection-full} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

We disable `setspace`'s patch and insert the spacing patch into the `table` environment ourselves.

If you don't change the document spacing and only plan on using a `setspace` environment for portions of your document without floats, the following shorter fix will suffice.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat\latex@xfloat
\makeatother


\begin{document}
jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{article-full,incollection-full} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses
\begin{table}[!htp]
          \vspace{-4mm}
\caption{SBL - Model Summaries}
\label{tab:popular_sparse_bayesian_models}
%\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{2cm}p{2.5cm}}
\hline\hline
& & &  \\
\hline  
\textbf{Ref.} & \textbf{Method}  & \textbf{Model} & \textbf{Priors}  \\ [1.0ex] 
\hline
RVMs\\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{8pt}\cite{article-full} & RVM  & Sigmoid & Zero-mean Gaussian \\
\rule{0pt}{8pt}\cite{article-full} & Fast RVM & Sigmoid & Zero-mean Gaussian  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{article-full,incollection-full} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses

jointly encourages sparsity to features and samples. However, in order to select features for non-linear basis functions, we have to differentiate, which leads to high computational costs. As future work, we plan to use incremental learning \cite{article-full,incollection-full} to reduce the computational costs. We also plan to design an online strategy [43] for joint feature and classifier learning. Also, PFCVMLP focuses on the supervised binary classification. It would be interesting to extend PFCVMLP to solve multi-class problems [24, 41] and semi-supervised form [22]. Finally, we aim to use PFCVMLP in other areas of research, such as in bioinformatics problems and clinical diagnoses

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats Great !  ---- I have been looking to find this thing since 24 hours. Many thanks for helping me out on this.